# CMake-generated Makefile: "make <a target>" opens shell inside shell repeatedly

Tags: windows-7, cmake, mingw32

I open a cmd console, go to where the Makefile is and run "make help", for instance.  Instead of listing the available targets, make seems to just run cmd inside cmd again and again for each target.  I can go back by typing "exit", "exit", "exit", etc. until I'm back to my original cmd prompt.  All other targets are rendered the same way.

I configured (using Cmake GUI) CMake to use MinGW tools, indicated the correct source and build dirs.  Everything regarding environment seems ok per the tests performed by CMake.

Please, help, I have no clue of what is going on.  That's very odd.

Here is the "help" target from the Makefile generated by Cmake (I edited out some @echoes during investigation).  In this case, make opens three cmd prompts in tandem instead of printing the information in the @echo commands.

```
# Help Target
help:
    @echo The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
    @echo ... all (the default if no target is provided)
    @echo ... clean
.PHONY : help
```

Please ask any information you want.  I didn't paste the entire Makefile or CMakeCache.txt because they are quite large.  If you need them, please ask.

This is my CMakeLists.txt, it is quite simple:

```
#

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 

project (HELLO) 

add_library (mylib MainLibClass.cpp)

add_executable(myprogram main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myprogram mylib)
```

Comment: Just to eliminate potential background problems: what happens if you type the commands which 'make help' executes by hand? Or when you put them in a batch file?

Comment: Just a guess. Are you using the right make command, the mingw one? Shouldn't it be something like "mingw32-make"?

Comment: @Angew, there are only echo commands in "help" target.  echo just prints out the following text.  The echo command just runs fine manually.

Comment: @guini, I'm using MinGW's make.exe from \MinGW\msys\1.0\bin.  Is it ok?  Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho I get the same behavior when I use \MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe . You could try using \MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe .